# Python - open pdf file to specific page/section

Tags: python, pdf

Is it possible to open a pdf from within Python such that it goes to a specific page or section?  What I am thinking is to have it open a help file (pdf) and jump to the section that the help is being requested for.

Comment: What would you be using to open the file?

Comment: Take a look at pypdf. http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/

Comment: I would like to use the default pdf reader to open the file.  I am pretty sure this would be Adobe Reader 99.9% of the time.  Perhaps there is a way to open Adobe Reader to a specific page?  I now suspect I will have to do this through Adobe Reader, and not necessarily through Python.  I will also probably have to put the Python code in a `try` block in case the user does not have Adobe Reader installed.  Does anybody know of a argument to send Adobe Reader to open to a specific page?

Comment: It seems that there is no argument to open Adobe Reader on a certain page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/619203/183791

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are two basic ideas

### Case 1: you want to open the file in Python

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader, PageObject

pdf_toread = PdfFileReader(path_to_your_pdf)

# 1 is the number of the page
page_one = pdf_toread.getPage(1)

# This will dump the content (unicode string)
# According to the doc, the formatting is dependent on the
# structure of the document
print page_one.extractText()
```

As for the section, you can have a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1851011/493211)

### Case 2: you want to call acrobat to open your file at a specific page

From this [Acrobat help document](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf), you can pass this to a subprocess:

```
import subprocess
import os

path_to_pdf = os.path.abspath('C:\test_file.pdf')
# I am testing this on my Windows Install machine
path_to_acrobat = os.path.abspath('C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe') 

# this will open your document on page 12
process = subprocess.Popen([path_to_acrobat, '/A', 'page=12', path_to_pdf], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
```

Just a suggestion: if you want to open the file at a specific section, you could use the parameter `search=wordList` where `wordlist` is a list of words seperated by spaces. The document will be opened and the search will be performed, the first result of it being highlighted. This way, as a `wordlist`, you can try to put the name of the section.

Comment: It is not necessary to open and read the PDF in Python.  I would like to open the PDF with the default PDF reader and go to a specific page.

Comment: I am having a problem with this. My acrobat reader opens up and says "there was an error in opening the document. the filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect". I am unable to find a solution to this or even identify the error.

Comment: ```print(pageObj.extractText())``` return None or '', why?