# PDF Viewer for Python Tkinter

Tags: python, pdf, view, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am currently looking for a possibility to display PDF Files inside a Tkinter application (displaying them e.g. in a Frame widget or similar).

Is there already a solution for this problem?

I already searched SO, used ddg an others but did not find anything for that purpose. Only thing I found was how to print the contents of a tk.Canvas to PDF - is there a way to load a PDF into a Canvas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**!!! ATTENTION !!!

   !!! THIS ONLY WORKS FOR PYTHON 2 !!!!**

***I am currently working on an update for python3***

viranthas pypdfocr is not working properly with python 3.
For use with python 2, happily use the version below.

Finally I came to a solution I can work with.

Using pypdfocr and its pypdfocr_gs library I call

`pypdfocr.pypdfocr_gs.PyGs({}).make_img_from_pdf(pdf_file)`

to retrieve jpg images and then I use PIL to get ImageTk.PhotoImage instances from it and use them in my code.

```
ImageTk.PhotoImage(_img_file_handle)
```

Will add a proper example as soon as I can.

**Edit:**

As promised here comes the code

```
    import pypdfocr.pypdfocr_gs as pdfImg
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

    import glob, os

    root=tk.Tk()

    __f_tmp=glob.glob(pdfImg.PyGs({}).make_img_from_pdf("\tmp\test.pdf")[1])[0]
    #                             ^ this is needed for a "default"-Config
    __img=Image.open(__f_tmp)

    __tk_img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(__img)

    ttk.Label(root, image=__tk_img).grid()

    __img.close()
    os.remove(__f_tmp)

    root.mainloop()
```

**Edit:**

Using viranthas pypdfocr version there seems to be a bug inside the handling of Windows 10 and pythons subprocess:

```
# extract from pypdfocr_gs:
def _run_gs(self, options, output_filename, pdf_filename):
        try:
            cmd = '%s -q -dNOPAUSE %s -sOutputFile="%s" "%s" -c quit' % (self.binary, options, output_filename, pdf_filename)

            logging.info(cmd)        

            # Change this line for Windows 10:
            # out = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
            out = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
# end of extract
```

Answer (score 2):

2021, a way that worked for me on windows 10. [From](https://codingshiksha.com/python/python-tkinter-gui-script-to-load-and-view-pdf-document-using-tkpdfviewer-library-full-project-for-beginners/)

```sh
pip install tkPDFViewer
```

Then

```py
# Importing tkinter to make gui in python
import os
from tkinter import *

# Importing tkPDFViewer to place pdf file in gui.
# In tkPDFViewer library there is
# an tkPDFViewer module. That I have imported as pdf
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf
# Initializing tk
root = Tk()

# Set the width and height of our root window.
root.geometry("550x750")

# creating object of ShowPdf from tkPDFViewer.
v1 = pdf.ShowPdf()

# Adding pdf location and width and height.
v2 = v1.pdf_view(root,
                 pdf_location=r"C:\repositories\dg_ml\dg_ml_models\deliverynote\deliverynote\visualize\tmp\annotated\243712_637477949668712907_Scan2021-02-01_174914.pdf",
                 width=50, height=100)

# Placing Pdf in my gui.
v2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can we set the border to the pdf_view widget? If possible then how?

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be deprecated because a dependency has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Your search keywords are "python pdf parsing".  Google turns up this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848464/advanced-pdf-parsing-using-python-extracting-text-without-tables-etc-whats) and [pdfminer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/).  There was also this [review](http://css.dzone.com/articles/pdf-reading) that settled on pdfminer as the best of a not-great choice, but it is two years older than the latest pdfminer release.  There are also pdfminer versions for [Py3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer3k/1.3.0) and for [2&3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer.six/20140915).

Comment: Thanks for the advice terry but i do not want to parse them i would like to bring them into a tkinter gui similar to a document view including zoom.

Comment: *Something* has to parse the bytes in a .pdf file and convert the parsed objects to a displayable bitmap image.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to "revert" the process of the tk.canvas PostScript functionality?

Comment: I do not know of a tk function to do that.  Again, *something* would have to parse the file.  There might a tcl/tk extension that could help, but I have never looked into them.