# pypdfocr issue: 'pdfimages' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, pdf

I have been trying to convert a pdf to an image and display on a tkinter canvas. I have it working but every time i convert a pdf i get this error(I borrowed this code from here ([PDF Viewer for Python Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653929/pdf-viewer-for-python-tkinter)). Is there anyway to just set it to 300DPI? or better yet why is this happening and what can i do about it? I have searched for hours trying to find other convert pdf to image solutions and came up with nothing I could figure out easily(I am quite new to python).

pypdfocr issue: 'pdfimages' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. WARNING: Could not execute pdfimages to calculate DPI (try installing xpdf or poppler?), so defaulting to 300dpi

```
import pypdfocr.pypdfocr_gs as pdfImg
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

import glob, os

root=tk.Tk()

__f_tmp = glob.glob(pdfImg.PyGs({}).make_img_from_pdf("1.pdf")[1])[0]
   #                             ^ this is needed for an "default"-Config
__img=Image.open(__f_tmp)



__tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(__img.resize((800,1000), Image.ANTIALIAS))


ttk.Label(root, image=__tk_img).grid()

__img.close()
os.remove(__f_tmp)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried "installing xpdf or poppler" as the error message helpfully suggests?

Comment: @Chris : I tried and failed. I could not find an .exe to install either. I did find a few binaries but in truth i was unsure what to do with them. I read a few places that building these for windows was difficult. I am working under windows.

Comment: Well, you'll have to install one of them. Maybe this question will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381713/how-to-install-poppler-on-windows

Comment: @Chris, thank you very much. I did find this before posting here and even downloaded the poppler windows 0.37. The issue is it looks like a compiled program. How would i make my python program aware of these executables?

Comment: It looks like you actually need the `pdfimages` program, which is included in the `poppler-utils` package on my Ubuntu system. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be included in the list of releases from that question. I don't have a Windows machine available for testing at the moment, and I generally avoid installing code from strange resources, but the [`.7z` archive on this page](http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/) seems to include it. Make sure to add it to your `%PATH%` and try again. You may have to ask `pypdfocr` to use `pdfimages.exe` instead of `pdfimages` somehow.

Comment: OK so i went into the pypdffocr_gs.py and found there it references pdfimages. I am now trying to find a way to point to my pdfimages.exe that i have placed within my python program folder - no luck so far. Also, I am embarrassed to say I have very little experience setting the %PATH% environmental variables. I did it for python when i installed and that is it. Any additional instruction would be most appreciated.